# react-select when change view missing selected value

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How can I keep selected options by react-select async? What I mean I have the following component which is inside of a form with multiple steps when I step back to the part where I use AsyncSelect I see placeholder and load options fire again(get all value from API) selected values. how to keep the selected value. this is my AsyncDropDown.js :

```
<AsyncSelect
            styles={customStyles}
            cacheOptions
            loadOptions={loadOptions}
            defaultOptions
            onChange={handleChange}
            isRtl={true}
            isSearchable={false}
            classNamePrefix='myDropDown'
            placeholder={'(پیش فرض گروه فعال)'}
        />
```

and this `loadOtions` function :

```
const loadOptions = (selectedOption, callback) => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('Token')
        let udid = localStorage.getItem('UUID')
        let xml = `body of request`;
        axios.post('myurl.com', xml, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8' } }).then(function (response) {
            //console.log(response)
            var options = {
                attributeNamePrefix: "@_",
                attrNodeName: "attr", //default is 'false'
                textNodeName: "#text",
                ignoreAttributes: true,
                ignoreNameSpace: false,
                allowBooleanAttributes: false,
                parseNodeValue: true,
                parseAttributeValue: false,
                trimValues: true,
                cdataTagName: "__cdata", //default is 'false'
                cdataPositionChar: "\\c",
                localeRange: "", //To support non english character in tag/attribute values.
                parseTrueNumberOnly: false,
                attrValueProcessor: a => he.decode(a, { isAttributeValue: true }),//default is a=>a
                tagValueProcessor: a => he.decode(a) //default is a=>a
            };
            // Intermediate obj
            var tObj = parser.getTraversalObj(response.data, options);
            var jsonObj = parser.convertToJson(tObj, options);

            if (jsonObj["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"].GetAllCategoriesResponse.GetAllCategoriesResult["diffgr:diffgram"].DocumentElement != null) {
                var jsonDropDownDetails = jsonObj["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"].GetAllCategoriesResponse.GetAllCategoriesResult["diffgr:diffgram"].DocumentElement.CATEGORY
                jsonDropDownDetails.map(item => {
                    const data = { value: item.CATEGORYNAME, label: item.CATEGORYNAME, index: item.CATEGORYID }
                    setDropDownOptions(dropDownOptions.push(data))
                })
                callback(dropDownOptions)
            }
            setIsLoading(false)
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("erorr in DropDown : " + error)
        })
    };
```

and this is `handelChange` function :

```
   const handleChange = selectedOption => {
        setSelectedOption(selectedOption)
        props.parentCallBack(selectedOption)

    };
```

this is the Async Dropdown component use this component to the main view when in the main view go to the next view and get back to the main view missing selected Value and show placeHolder and call loadOptions function again and call API. how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retain values of your form fields when you click/next or previous:

- Create a main form component say `MasterForm` and and render the form-steps say `Step1` and `Step2`(which holds your input fields etc).
- Maintain the `value` of your `select` in `MasterForm` and the `values` and `onChangeHandlers` the form steps.

I have created a [working demo of react-select multi step form](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-multi-step-qiqnz?file=/src/MasterForm.js)

**MasterForm:**

```js
...
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Step1
          value={this.state.step1SelectValue}
          handleChange={e => {
            this.setState({ step1SelectValue: e });
          }}
          currentStep={this.state.currentStep}
        />
        <Step2
          value={this.state.step2SelectValue}
          handleChange={e => {
            this.setState({ step2SelectValue: e });
          }}
          currentStep={this.state.currentStep}
        />
        {this.previousButton()}
        {this.nextButton()}
      </>
    );
  }
  ...
```

**Step1.js**

```js
...
<AsyncSelect
          cacheOptions
          loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
          defaultOptions
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}
          isRtl={true}
          isSearchable={false}
          classNamePrefix="myDropDown"
          placeholder={"(پیش فرض گروه فعال)"}
          value={this.props.value}
...
```

Note:

- You seem to not use search feature in your select. So I guess you can simply use normal `Select` and handle data fetching on your own in componentDidMount. See `Step2` in my [code demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-multi-step-qiqnz?file=/src/Step2.js)
- If you don't want to execute your `loadOptions` function for all the re-renders consider to use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) . Note that useMemo is available in functional components